# Trying to run unittest module on file and... ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.py'

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have looked through a lot of questions that have similar issues to the one I'm having but I haven't been able to figure out why I can't run `python -m unittest test.py` from the console. I think it might be a `PATH` issue having to do with my Conda virtual environment. I'm just trying to create a simple Flask app the sends greetings messages to the client. My code seems fine but when I run `python -m unittest test.py` this is the message I get back...

```
    ======================================================================
ERROR: py (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brent/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.py'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)

echo $PATH                                                                                                 
/home/brent/anaconda3/envs/py39/bin /home/brent/anaconda3/condabin 
/usr/local/sbin/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /usr/bin/site_perl /usr/bin/vendor_perl 
/usr/bin/core_perl
```

If anyone has any idea of what I might be missing here, any help is appreciated. Please let me know if I didn't provide enough information and what you might want me to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I realized the issue was because the syntax to set `FLASK_APP=app.py` when running on the fish shell is different. It had me run it with the syntax of `set FLASK_APP app.py`.